# How apply new CSS in an project that already has?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, ganglia

I'm working in a project which already uses a `stylesheet`, but I would like to improve the website using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).
I tried to put the new `stylesheet`  in the project but something that was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wi2a.png):

[image: before]

Became [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRHEc.png):
[image: after]

So I just stop using `Foundation`, but I really would like to use it, but how ?
What did you guys do to apply a new `CSS` in a project that already has ?

**update**

```
<!-- CSS Ganglia -->
<link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.liveSearch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.flot.events.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- /CSS Ganglia -->

<!-- CSS Integra -->
<link type="text/css" href="css/integra/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- /CSS Integra -->

<!-- CSS Foundation -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation/normalize.css" />   -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation/foundation.css" />  -->
```

Comment: I would just include foundation and start again with a new stylesheet

Comment: In which order did you include the new stylesheet?

Comment: @Lowkase, this way (update the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very complicated process that you are going about performing here...  99.99% of the time you can not just "plug and play" so to speak with new style sheets.  For example it is likely that your two inputs up there have `float: left` defined in the old stylesheet.  The new stylesheet overwrote those styles and made them essentially `float: none` which broke the layout.

So, what should you do.

Duplicate the current site out to a development directory (just make a folder in the root directory called dev and duplicate the entire site inside that directory.  You'll use this directory to develop from without modifying a site that is currently live.

Include your foundation stylesheet/s below the current one.  Then slowly go through the old stylesheet and figure out whats being over-written and merge it to a new stylesheet.